# Asp.net www redirect to non www

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, iis

I have a site called farrukh.jaam.io ,when a user writes www.farrukh.jaam.io , then i want to redirect it to farrukh.jaam.io My site is in asp.net mvc and using IIS server.
Thanks.

Comment: using which iis version ??

Comment: IIS 8 but does it really matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
                        <match url="(.*)" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.farrukh.jaam\.io$" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="http://farrukh.jaam.io/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                    </rule>

 <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
```

Comment: <action type="Redirect" url="http://farrukh.jaam.io/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />

 i also want to add for https then how?

Comment: <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>

Comment: Thanks dear let me try